# JPA persist is inserting incorrect id value when cascading a child

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

This code is failing
I have an exising versioned value in the database, which I fetch using `entity manager.find`, and set on the entity.

```
VersionEntity version = entityManager.find(VersionEntity.class, 1);
entities.forEach(__ -> __.setVersion(version));
entities.forEach(entityManager::persist);
entityManager.flush();
```

I am specifically looking up and assigning version 1, so why would it even attempt to use version 2. I even tried `merge` and that didn't work.
My attributes are obviously wrong / incorrect.

Flush fails with

> ocal Exception Stack:
>   Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.1.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "t_quality_measurement" violates foreign key constraint "fk_t_quality_measurement_version"
>     **Detail: Key (version)=(2)** is not present in table "t_version".
>   Error Code: 0
>   Call: INSERT INTO T_QUALITY_MEASUREMENT (BRAND, DATE, KPICODE, KPICOMPAREVW, KPICOMPAREWT, KPIVALUE, ORGANISATIONUNIT, PHASE, PLANT, SERIES, SIGNALCOLOR, TECHNOLOGY, TEMPORALUNIT, VIEW) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>           bind => [14 parameters bound]
>   Query:

I am unsure of why it's trying to use a 2 when I specifically looked up 1.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_QUALITY_MEASUREMENT")
public class QualityMeasurementEntity extends Versioned implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(length = 100)
    private String series;
```

Versioned looks like this

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Versioned {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "version", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    protected VersionEntity version = null;

    public VersionEntity getVersion() { return version; }

    public void setVersion(VersionEntity version) { this.version = version; }
}
```

and the version entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_VERSION", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "pk_version", columnList = "id", unique = true)
})
@NamedQuery(name = "Version.findById", query = "SELECT v FROM VersionEntity v WHERE v.id = :id")
public class VersionEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "CREATED")
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @Column
    private Boolean active = false;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        created = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreated() { return created; }
    public void setCreated(LocalDateTime created) { this.created = created; }

    public Boolean getActive() { return active; }
    public void setActive(Boolean active) { this.active = active; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        VersionEntity version = (VersionEntity) o;
        return id.equals(version.id);
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() { return id.hashCode(); }
}
```

Comment: I don't see that it is attempting to insert any value for version: `version` does not appear in list of columns in the insert statement. As you have marked it as non-insertable and non-updateable  that is not surprising.  `@JoinColumn(name = "version", insertable = false, updatable = false)`

Comment: I am specifically looking up and assigning version 1, so why would it even attempt to insert version 2. I even tried merge and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to prevent the insert.
Change `@JoinColumn`

```
 @JoinColumn(name = "version")
```